# Create or replace a view via ODP for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, odp.net

Is it possible to create or replace an existing oracle view with Oracle Data Provider for .NET in C# program?

Tried to run an SQL script with the view definition but failed with the error :

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Script parsing/execution error    at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isFromEF)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

If anyone knows the answer or where I can look this up I would appreciate it.